# How do I line up the Age and Name input boxes without using javascript or tables

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to find a way to line up the input boxes for Name, Email, Age. The boxes are lined up for name and email. However, how do I change the width or margin to line up the input box to match that of name and email.

Also, how do I make the option value box bigger that accompany "Which option best describes your current role" label?

I have tried to adjust the width, margin to try to get the box to line up to email/age however it does not work. It seems that when I do margin-left it moves the label further away from the input box.

```css
#Title{
  text-align: center;
}
#description{
  text-align: center;
}
body{
  background-color: #a9d7d1;
  margin: 50px 200px 20px 200px;
}
#Survey-form{
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  text-align: center;

}

#Name{
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  display:inline-block;

}
#Email{
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  display:inline-block;

}
#Age{
  text-align: left;
  width: 200px;
  height: 25px;
  display:inline-block;
}

label[for=role]{
margin-left: -345px;
width: 40px;

select required {
    width: 450px;
    margin: 10px;
}

div{

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>Survey Form </title>
<!-- Survey Form. -->
<link href="SurveyForm.css" rel=stylesheet>

</head>
<body>

  <h1 id="Title"> Survey Form </h1>


  <form id="Survey-form">
    <p id="description">Let us know how we can improve freeCodeCamp </p>

  <!-- <p>  -->
  <div>
   <br />  <label>Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" placeholder="Enter your name">
  </div>
  <div>
   <br />  <label>Email:</label>
    <input type="email" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="Enter your email"><br>
</div>

<div>
 <br />  <label> Age:</label>
  <input type="number" min = "18" max="110" name="Age" id="Age" placeholder="Age">
</div>

<div>
 <br />  <label for="role">Which option best describes your current role?</label>
    <select required>
      <option value="selected disabled">Select an option </option>
    <option value="Student">Student</option>
    <option value="FullTimeJob">Full Time Job</option>
    <option value="FullTimeLearner">Full Time Learner</option>
    <option value="NotToSay">Prefer Not to Say</option>
    <option value="Other">Other</option>
  </select>
</div>

<p>How likely is that you would recommend
  <br>freeCodeCamp to a friend?

 <br><input type="radio" name="recommend" class="recommend" value="Definetly"> Definetly
  <br>  <input type="radio" name="recommend" class="recommend" value="Maybe"> Maybe
<br>  <input type="radio" name="recommend" class="recommend" value="NotSure"> Not Sure



<p>  <label for="FCC">What do you like most in FCC: </label>
    <select required>
      <option value="selected disabled">Select an option </option>
    <option value="Challenges">Challenges</option>
    <option value="Projects">Projects</option>
    <option value="Community">Community</option>
    <option value="Open Source">Open Source</option>
  </select>

  <p>Things that should be improved in the future.<br />(Check all that apply):
<br />  Front-end Projects: <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="Front-end Projects">
<br />  Back-end Projects: <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="Back-end Projects" >
<br />  Challenges: <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="Challenges">
<br />  Open Source Community: <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="Open Source Community">
  <br />  Gitter help rooms: <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="Gitter help rooms" >
  <br />  Videos: <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="Videos" >
  <br />  City Meetups: <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="City Meetups" >
  <br />  Wiki: <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="Wiki" >
  <br />  Forum: <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="Forum" >
  <br />  Additional Courses: <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="Additional Courses" >
<p>
  Any Comments or Suggestions?
  <textarea rows="4" cols="44" name="comment" form="usrform">
     Enter your comment here...</textarea>

   </p><input type="submit" value="Submit">


</form>

      </body>
      </html>
```

The boxes should line up and I want to make the select an option box bigger for the label Which option best describes your current role?

Comment: Sorry, I think I did a bad job explaining. I don't want the label Name to be above the input box. The way I have it aligned is correct however the age input box does not match the positioning of the Name Email boxes. I am trying to imitate this form right here but not use their code: https://codepen.io/freeCodeCamp/full/VPaoNP

Comment: For starters you have a space before Age in your code. If you want to learn how to make custom input select check out w3schools for the basics. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_custom_select

Comment: try this style   `label,input{display:inline)`

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, Wrap your input elements using wrapper `.row` then divide into two columns `.right, .left` set relevent widths accordingly and use `display: inline-block;` to create grid.

You can use `ul` to create `radio` and `checkbox` list like I did below and get rid of  `<br/>`

```css
.form {
  max-width: 900px;
  width: 75%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}

div.row {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

div.right {
  width: 45%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

div.left {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.input-list {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

.radio-li, .checkbox-li {
  display: block;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.radio, .checkbox {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
           <div class="left">
             <label>Name:</label>
           </div>
           <div class="right">
             <input type="text" name="name" class="input" placeholder="Enter your name">
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
           <div class="left">
             <label for="role">Which option best describes your current role?</label>
           </div>
           <div class="right">
              <select>
                 <option value="selected disabled">Select an option </option>
                 <option value="Student">Student</option>
                 <option value="FullTimeJob">Full Time Job</option>
                 <option value="FullTimeLearner">Full Time Learner</option>
                 <option value="NotToSay">Prefer Not to Say</option>
                 <option value="Other">Other</option>
              </select>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
           <div class="left">
             <label for="role">How likely is that you would recommend freeCodeCamp to a friend?</label>
           </div>
           <div class="right">
             <ul class="input-list">
               <li class="radio-li"><label>Definetly<input type="radio" name="recommend" class="recommend radio" value="Definetly"></label></li>
               <li class="radio-li"><label>Maybe <input type="radio" name="recommend" class="recommend radio" value="Maybe"></label></li>
               <li class="radio-li"><label>Not Sure <input type="radio" name="recommend" class="recommend radio" value="NotSure"></label></li>
             </ul>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
           <div class="left">
             <label for="role">Things that should be improved in the future.(Check all that apply):</label>
           </div>
           <div class="right">
             <ul class="input-list">
               <li class="checkbox-li"><label>Front-end Projects: <input type="checkbox" name="sports" class="checkbox" value="Front-end Projects"></label></li>
               <li class="checkbox-li"><label>Back-end Projects: <input type="checkbox" name="sports" class="checkbox" value="Back-end Projects" ></li>
               <li class="checkbox-li"><label>Challenges: <input type="checkbox" name="sports" class="checkbox" value="Challenges"></label></li>
             </ul>
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="row">
           <div class="left">
             <label for="role"> Any Comments or Suggestions?</label>
           </div>
           <div class="right">
             <textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="comment" form="usrform">Enter your comment here...</textarea>
           </div>
         </div>
```